# В wordpress пробую писать плагин, не подключается файл стилей и js

Tags: css, wordpress, wp-plugin

Не подключается файл стилей и js, подскажите что не так?

index.php:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: my-favorites
Description: favorites
Author: Alex
Version: 1.0
*/

require __DIR__ . '/functions.php';

add_filter('the_content', 'my_favorites_content');
```

functions.php:

```
<?php
function my_favorites_content($content) {
    if( !is_single() || !is_user_logged_in()) {
        return $content;
    }
    return  '<p class="my-favorites-link"><a href="#">Добавить в избранное</a> </p>' . $content ;
}

function my_favorites_scripts() {
    if( !is_single() || !is_user_logged_in() ) return;
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-favorites-scripts', plugins_url('/js/my-favorites-scripts.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-favorites-style', plugins_url('/css/my-favorites-style.css', __FILE__) );
}
```

my-favorites-style.css:

```
p.my-favorites-link a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-style: dotted;
}

p.my-favorites-link a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас нет вызова функции my_favorites_scripts.

Добавьте после нее строку

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_favorites_scripts' );
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Welcome, как говорится )